# Split list of strings into constituent characters

Tags: python

I have these lines of code to split labels into characters and put them into a list.

```
Labels=[226md, 22d5n, 2356g, 23mdg, 23n88, 243mm,...]

def split(string):
    for i in range(len(labels)):
        return [char for char in string[i]]
for i in range(len(labels)):
    x=split(labels)
    print(x)
```

However, my output comes out as

```
['2', '2', '6', 'm', 'd']
['2', '2', '6', 'm', 'd']
['2', '2', '6', 'm', 'd']
['2', '2', '6', 'm', 'd']
['2', '2', '6', 'm', 'd']
['2', '2', '6', 'm', 'd']
...
```

instead of

```
['2', '2', '6', 'm', 'd']
['2', '2', 'd', '5', 'n']
['2', '3', '5', '6', 'g']
['2', '3', 'm', 'd', 'g']
['2', '3', 'n', '8', '8']
['2', '4', '3', 'm', 'm']
...
```

Each string is consistently 5 characters long. How can I get the preferred output so I can split each label into its constituent characters?

Comment: Shouldn't the labels be in quotes?

Comment: Did you mean: `for n in Labels: print(list(n))`?

Comment: Maybe `list(map(list,Labels))`.

Comment: `Labels=[226md, 22d5n, 2356g, 23mdg, 23n88, 243mm,` produces a `SyntaxError` please fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
Labels=['226md', '22d5n', '2356g', '23mdg', '23n88', '243mm']

x = [[j for j in i] for i in Labels]
```

Value of `x`:

```
[['2', '2', '6', 'm', 'd'],
 ['2', '2', 'd', '5', 'n'],
 ['2', '3', '5', '6', 'g'],
 ['2', '3', 'm', 'd', 'g'],
 ['2', '3', 'n', '8', '8'],
 ['2', '4', '3', 'm', 'm']]
```

Or if you just want to print the output:

```
Labels=['226md', '22d5n', '2356g', '23mdg', '23n88', '243mm']

for i in Labels:
    print([j for j in i])
```

Output:

```
['2', '2', '6', 'm', 'd']
['2', '2', 'd', '5', 'n']
['2', '3', '5', '6', 'g']
['2', '3', 'm', 'd', 'g']
['2', '3', 'n', '8', '8']
['2', '4', '3', 'm', 'm']
```

Also, it is worth noting that you can swap `[j for j in i]` for just `list(i)`. The reason your code does not work is because your `return` statement halts the execution of the code. Your `split` function (its name should be changed as `split` is a built in python function) could just be changed to this:

```
def split(string):
    return [list(i) for i in string]
```

And then change your `for` loop to just `split(Labels)`.

Comment: You shouldn't use a list comprehension for side effects. This is a bad practice: `[print([j for j in i]) for i in Labels]` because it creates a list of a bunch of `None` values for no reason.

Comment: I think that: `[j for j in i]` is expressed better as: `list(i)`.

Comment: @Mark i changed the list comprehension into a `for` loop. @quamrana I just used list comprehension so it is easier to see what the code is doing but i did note that `list(i)` works to.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because in the body of the method `split` you are always returning the characters of the first label. In fact the `return` statement halts the execution of the code and returns immidiately.

To achive the result you are describing you should save the rows into a cumulative variable and then return it when the loop has finished:

```
Labels=["226md", "22d5n", "2356g", "23mdg", "23n88", "243mm",...]

def split(labels):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(labels)):
        result.append([char for char in string[i]])
    return result

split(Labels)
```

Plus, this way you don't need the last loop outside the function body because you are already iterating through all labels into the `split` function.